# Isomorphism of quotient containing Cauchy sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, ring-isomorphism

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $R$ be the ring of Cauchy sequences in $(\mathbb{Q}, |\cdot|_{p})$. Let $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq R$ be the ideal of all sequences converging to $0$, forming a maximal ideal of $R$.  Also, let $R_{0} = \{x \in R/\mathfrak{m} :  |x|_{p} \leq 1\}$.

> Prove that $R/\mathfrak{m} \cong R_{0}[\frac{1}{p}]$, in other words, for every $x \in R/\mathfrak{m}$ there is an $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $p^{n}x \in R_{0}$. Conclude that $R/\mathfrak{m} \cong Q(R_{0})$.

I have proven earlier that $R$ forms a commutative ring and that $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal of $R$.

**My attempt**: Suppose that $x \in R/\mathfrak{m}$ with $x = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n}$. Notice that this sequence does not converge to 0. Furthermore, it holds that $|x|_{p} = \lim_{n \to \infty} |x_{n}|_{p}$. Since $x_{n} = p^{k_{n}}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}$ voor integers $k_{n}, a_{n}, b_{n} \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\gcd(p, a_{n}b_{n}) = 1$, it follows that $|x_{n}| = p^{-k_{n}}$.

At this point, I would like to prove the existence of a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ for which $|x|_{p} = p^{-k}$.

We can now make a distinction of cases. If $k < 0$, then $|x|_{p} > 1$, so we can take $n = -k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. Then, $|p^nx|_{p} = |p^{-k}|_{p}|x|_{p} = p^{k}p^{-k} = 1$, and thus $p^n x \in R_{0}$. If $k \geq 0$, then it directly follows that $|x|_{p} = p^{-k} \leq 1$, so we can take $n = 0$. We conclude that there is always a $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $p^{n} x \in R_{0}$.

If anyone has hints or suggestions on how I could justify the existence of $k$ with the sequence, or if someone has suggestions on improvements, I would appreciate that.

Comment: I have fixed the formatting. As a hint, next time plase start with the definitions (like in my edit), so that the question is easier to understand. Also, you should add your own attempts to solve the problem. "No clue" questions will usually get closed per site policy.